# SecureRandom generates values of different length

Tags: java, salt

I have an application which I need to salt passwords.  In order to generate the salts I decided to use `SecureRandom`.  Everything works great when I am on my windows machine.  Then I tried to run my code on a Linux based machine (Centos 5) and everything broke.

I isolated the problem and created this test case:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] saltBytes = new byte[256];
    sr.nextBytes(saltBytes);
    String salt = new String(saltBytes);
    System.out.println(salt.length());
}
```

In windows the output is always 256, but on my Linux machine the output changes and is never 256.  It seems to always generate a salt that is smaller in length than 256.

Does anyone know why this occurs?

Solution:

I just changed new String line to `new String(saltbytes, "ASCII");`

Comment: You are not setting the charset of String, use `String(byte[] bytes, Charset charset)` constructor.

Comment: You shouldn't be attempting to put binary data in a text String.  This usually leads to confusion.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is character encoding. On linux that is usually utf-8, which is a variable length encoding. If you want a string, use base64 for it instead.